# Does this integral for $\zeta(s)$ converge for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$ (except the pole at $s=1$)?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, contour-integration, riemann-zeta

This [paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jmath/2013/181724/) contains the following integral (14) for $\zeta(s)$ with $s=\sigma+it$:

$$\zeta(s) = \frac{\pi}{2\,(s-1)}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(1/2+ix)^{1-s}}{\cosh^2(\pi x)} dx \qquad \sigma > 0$$

Contrary to the restriction on $\sigma$, numerical evidence suggests this integral is actually valid for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$ (except $s=1$).

Is this true?

**Added:**

The question has been answered in the comments. Just to share this yields these two beautiful integral expressions for entire Dirichlet series that are valid for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$:

\begin{align*}
\eta(s) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac12+ix\right)^{-s}+\left(\frac12-ix\right)^{-s}}{e^{\pi x}+e^{-\pi x}} dx
\\
\\
(s-1)\zeta(s) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac12+i\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^{1-s}+\left(\frac12-i\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^{1-s}}{\cosh(2x)-1} dx
\end{align*}

Comment: If one reads the cited article carefully and the references for the integral above, one discovers that this is a very old result of Lindelof (1905) quoted even in Wikipedia and of course it holds for all $s$ (that is trivial once one proves it holds for $s$ in some open set, as the integral is absolutely and locally uniformly convergent so it defines an entire function and $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is entire too so the identity principle implies the result); see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Integral_representations

Comment: @Conrad Thanks! It is surprising though, that such an elegant integral doesn't appear on the Zeta-function website itself or for instance on the list of integrals at DLMF https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.5. To me, it seems that this old Lindelof result doesn't get the spotlights it deserves in the literature.